# Incorrect Chinese punctuation spacing

Tags: punctuation, cjk, xecjk

When typing Chinese using `xeCJK`, periods and/or closing square brackets are too closely spaced together. How can I get more natural-looking spacings (e.g., tweaking `xeCJK` settings to match the Word output below) without manually inserting horizontal spaces like `\thinspace`?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{標楷體}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh" 
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt
\begin{document}
她說：「你好。」
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Output in Word:**

[image]

Comment: Comparing your two outputs, I would say adding a space respectively right after the column : and the chinese period。 will do the trick in this case. Or maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Jesse It's not customary to add a space after a period in Chinese texts (Note: There are no spaces in the Word document). So, for example, it would be a tremendous hassle if I had to insert manual spaces for every period in a lengthy document.

Comment: Indeed, I understand now, you are searching for a more general solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Punctuation spacing style is configurable. And there are 6 predefined styles in xeCJK: `quanjiao`, `banjiao`, `kaiming`, `hangmobanjiao`, `CCT` and `plain`. What you need is the `plain` style, which does not change the original width of punctuations. If you can read Chinese, you should read [the package document of `xeCJK`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.pdf) first.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{標楷體}
\xeCJKsetup{PunctStyle=plain}
\begin{document}
她說：「你好。」
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, I deleted the useless `\XeTeXlinebreaklocale` and `\XeTeXlinebreakskip` in your code. Note that `xeCJK` package provides more powerful functions than that.

Answer (score 2):

Would this be what you seek? [Idea inspired from here](http://latex-alive.tumblr.com/post/827168808/correct-punctuation-spaces)

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}%[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{標楷體}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh" 
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt

\makeatletter
\newcommand\myc{\@ifnextchar：{「}{：\@}}
\newcommand\myp{\@ifnextchar。{」}{。\@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

她說：「你好。」


她說\myc「你好\myp」
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, Jesse. But it's cumbersome to replace punctuation marks with commands, especially in longer pieces of writing.